# Will students without a Gradescope submission be able to see the test after grades are posted for the others?

Tags: teaching, exams

I have a class test graded, and want to publish/post the grades.
However, some students are expected to makeup the test, and I don't want them to see the test yet. Will a student with

> This student doesn't have a submission

be able to see the test, after the grades are posted?

My Gradescope is linked to the course Moodle. The test is currently hidden on Moodle. The test is normally handwritten and then uploaded by TAs.

Comment: I do not know the software, but isn't the integrity of the test compromised if you release it to part of the students, and only later to others? Independently of software?

Comment: Ask the TAs/professor/school.